# setAttribute javascript function not setting acttribute equal to the attribute value that's of selected option

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi guys so I'm trying to set attributes using jquery, but the code is not setting the attributes. What am I doing wrong. This is what I have tried :

---

HTML

```
<select id="track_type_selected">
  <option value="0" >51 Track 3m</option>
  <option value="1" >64 Track 3m</option>
  <option value="2" >103 Track 3m</option>
</select>
```

Javascript

```
var e = document.getElementById("track_type_selected");
  var selectedIndex = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
  if(selectedIndex==0){
      $("#required_tracks_id").setAttribute("sku","TRACK3");
  }
  if(selectedIndex==1){
      $("#required_tracks_id").setAttribute("sku","TRK30");
  }
  if(selectedIndex==2){
      $("#required_tracks_id").setAttribute("sku","TRACK-1033");
  }
```

Comment: *"why my code is not working."* How do you know it's not working? What is happening? Which errors do you get?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In JQuery you can use attr function to get or set any element Attribute to get an element attribute like this.

```
$("#required_tracks_id").attr("sku");
```

and to set an element attribute

```
$("#required_tracks_id").attr("sku", "Value");
```

in your case use code as bellow

```
var e = document.getElementById("track_type_selected");
var selectedIndex = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
if(selectedIndex==0){
    $("#required_tracks_id").attr("sku","TRACK3");
}
if(selectedIndex==1){
    $("#required_tracks_id").attr("sku","TRK30");
}
if(selectedIndex==2){
    $("#required_tracks_id").attr("sku","TRACK-1033");
}
```

Comment: i will accept after 8 minutes. not allowed to accept within 8 min

Comment: Your answer will be more helpful if you explained why `attr` needs to be used.

Comment: in JQuery there is no function named setAttribute, but you cal use attr function to get or set any element Attribute to get an element attribute like this $("#required_tracks_id").attr("sku");

Comment: You can [edit] your answer to add that information so it's not lost in the comments.

Comment: Also... with custom attributes it is recommended that you use `data-` attributes, e.g. `data-sku`, then it's a matter of accessing the [element's dataset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) or using [jQuery's own `.data()` API](https://api.jquery.com/data/).

Answer (score 1):

The reason it didn't work was because you were mixing vanilla JS with jQuery. You obtained the #required_tracks_id via jQuery selector, but setAttribute() is a JS function. So, you could do either of these:

```
document.querySelector("#required_tracks_id").setAttribute("sku", "xxx");
```

Or

```
$("#required_tracks_id").attr("sku", "xxx");
```

Comment: Oh ok I see. makes sense now. Thank you